# Version 5.31.0 seems to break the CiviCase Extension

Tags: extension, civicase, core

We have the CiviCase (uk.co.compucorp.civicase) extension on our site. It's updated to the latest commit (52d0fbf31c5f4b4fe2a2523c9cec42bfbbec1e58). It was working fine in 5.30.

However, when I upgrade to 5.31.0, it breaks Case management (clicking on a case from Manage Cases brings up a blank screen, we can't see the activity in a case from the Manage Case screen, etc), and my Firefox console throws a ton of angular.js errors. We also get a SQL error in the Civi log (there is a field missing from the group by of a query, and only_full_group_by is turned on, so that breaks).

The only thing I've done is the upgrade from 5.30 to 5.31.0. No other changes have been made.

Since this is integration between core and an extension, I'm not sure who to bring this up with. So I'm noting it here for now. But if you can point me to the write place to put more details, I'm happy to do that.

Here are some of the console log errors I get (not sure this will help track things down):

```
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 13
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 40
    jQuery 8
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 23
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 23
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 21
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 21
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 28
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 26
    jQuery 8
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 26
    jQuery 8
angular.js:99
This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features! a
XHRGEThttps://crm.thespectrumworks.org/civicrm/ajax/rest?entity=Case&action=getdetails&json=%7B%22id%22%3A%2219%22%2C%22return%22%3A%5B%22subject%22%2C%22details%22%2C%22contact_id%22%2C%22case_type_id%22%2C%22case_type_id.case_type_category%22%2C%22status_id%22%2C%22contacts%22%2C%22start_date%22%2C%22end_date%22%2C%22is_deleted%22%2C%22activity_summary%22%2C%22activity_count%22%2C%22category_count%22%2C%22tag_id.name%22%2C%22tag_id.color%22%2C%22tag_id.description%22%2C%22tag_id.parent_id%22%2C%22related_case_ids%22%5D%2C%22case_type_id.case_type_category%22%3A%22cases%22%2C%22api.Case.getcaselist.relatedCasesByContact%22%3A%7B%22case_type_id.case_type_category%22%3A%22cases%22%2C%22contact_id%22%3A%7B%22IN%22%3A%22%24value.contact_id%22%7D%2C%22id%22%3A%7B%22!%3D%22%3A%22%24value.id%22%7D%2C%22is_deleted%22%3A0%2C%22return%22%3A%5B%22case_type_id%22%2C%22start_date%22%2C%22end_date%22%2C%22status_id%22%2C%22contacts%22%2C%22subject%22%5D%7D%2C%22api.Case.getcaselist.linkedCases%22%3A%7B%22case_type_id.case_type_category%22%3A%22cases%22%2C%22id%22%3A%7B%22IN%22%3A%22%24value.related_case_ids%22%7D%2C%22is_deleted%22%3A0%2C%22return%22%3A%5B%22case_type_id%22%2C%22start_date%22%2C%22end_date%22%2C%22status_id%22%2C%22contacts%22%2C%22subject%22%5D%7D%2C%22api.Activity.get.recentCommunication%22%3A%7B%22case_id%22%3A%2219%22%2C%22is_current_revision%22%3A1%2C%22is_test%22%3A0%2C%22activity_type_id%22%3A%7B%22!%3D%22%3A%22Bulk+Email%22%7D%2C%22activity_type_id.grouping%22%3A%7B%22LIKE%22%3A%22%25communication%25%22%7D%2C%22status_id.filter%22%3A1%2C%22options%22%3A%7B%22limit%22%3A5%2C%22sort%22%3A%22activity_date_time+DESC%22%7D%2C%22return%22%3A%5B%22subject%22%2C%22details%22%2C%22activity_type_id%22%2C%22status_id%22%2C%22source_contact_name%22%2C%22target_contact_name%22%2C%22assignee_contact_name%22%2C%22activity_date_time%22%2C%22is_star%22%2C%22original_id%22%2C%22tag_id.name%22%2C%22tag_id.description%22%2C%22tag_id.color%22%2C%22file_id%22%2C%22is_overdue%22%2C%22case_id%22%5D%7D%2C%22api.Activity.get.tasks%22%3A%7B%22case_id%22%3A%2219%22%2C%22is_current_revision%22%3A1%2C%22is_test%22%3A0%2C%22activity_type_id%22%3A%7B%22!%3D%22%3A%22Bulk+Email%22%7D%2C%22activity_type_id.grouping%22%3A%7B%22LIKE%22%3A%22%25task%25%22%7D%2C%22status_id.filter%22%3A0%2C%22options%22%3A%7B%22limit%22%3A5%2C%22sort%22%3A%22activity_date_time+ASC%22%7D%2C%22return%22%3A%5B%22subject%22%2C%22details%22%2C%22activity_type_id%22%2C%22status_id%22%2C%22source_contact_name%22%2C%22target_contact_name%22%2C%22assignee_contact_name%22%2C%22activity_date_time%22%2C%22is_star%22%2C%22original_id%22%2C%22tag_id.name%22%2C%22tag_id.description%22%2C%22tag_id.color%22%2C%22file_id%22%2C%22is_overdue%22%2C%22case_id%22%5D%7D%2C%22api.Activity.get.nextActivitiesWhichIsNotMileStone%22%3A%7B%22case_id%22%3A%2219%22%2C%22status_id%22%3A%7B%22!%3D%22%3A%22Completed%22%7D%2C%22activity_type_id%22%3A%7B%22!%3D%22%3A%22Bulk+Email%22%7D%2C%22activity_type_id.grouping%22%3A%7B%22NOT+LIKE%22%3A%22%25milestone%25%22%7D%2C%22options%22%3A%7B%22limit%22%3A1%7D%2C%22return%22%3A%5B%22subject%22%2C%22details%22%2C%22activity_type_id%22%2C%22status_id%22%2C%22source_contact_name%22%2C%22target_contact_name%22%2C%22assignee_contact_name%22%2C%22activity_date_time%22%2C%22is_star%22%2C%22original_id%22%2C%22tag_id.name%22%2C%22tag_id.description%22%2C%22tag_id.color%22%2C%22file_id%22%2C%22is_overdue%22%2C%22case_id%22%5D%7D%2C%22api.Activity.getcount.scheduled%22%3A%7B%22case_id%22%3A%2219%22%2C%22is_current_revision%22%3A1%2C%22is_deleted%22%3A0%2C%22activity_type_id%22%3A%7B%22!%3D%22%3A%22Bulk+Email%22%7D%2C%22status_id%22%3A%22Scheduled%22%7D%2C%22api.Activity.getcount.scheduled_overdue%22%3A%7B%22case_id%22%3A%2219%22%2C%22is_current_revision%22%3A1%2C%22is_deleted%22%3A0%2C%22is_overdue%22%3A1%2C%22activity_type_id%22%3A%7B%22!%3D%22%3A%22Bulk+Email%22%7D%2C%22status_id%22%3A%22Scheduled%22%7D%2C%22api.CustomValue.getalltreevalues%22%3A%7B%22entity_id%22%3A%22%24value.id%22%2C%22entity_type%22%3A%22Case%22%2C%22return%22%3A%5B%22custom_group.id%22%2C%22custom_group.name%22%2C%22custom_group.title%22%2C%22custom_field.name%22%2C%22custom_field.label%22%2C%22custom_value.display%22%2C%22custom_group.style%22%5D%7D%2C%22api.Relationship.get%22%3A%7B%22case_id%22%3A%2219%22%2C%22return%22%3A%5B%22id%22%2C%22relationship_type_id%22%2C%22contact_id_a%22%2C%22contact_id_b%22%2C%22description%22%2C%22end_date%22%2C%22is_active%22%2C%22start_date%22%5D%2C%22api.Contact.get%22%3A%7B%22contact_id%22%3A%22%24value.contact_id_b%22%7D%7D%2C%22sequential%22%3A1%7D
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 653ms]

Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 4
    jQuery 8
    Angular 23
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 4
    jQuery 8
    Angular 23
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 3
    jQuery 8
    <anonymous> button.js:110
    <anonymous> button.js:125
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 12
    jQuery 8
    Angular 23
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 12
    jQuery 8
    Angular 23
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 14
angular.js:99
GEThttps://crm.thespectrumworks.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/js/jquery/jquery.crmEditable.js?r=hPZWD
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2ms]

XHRGEThttps://crm.thespectrumworks.org/civicrm/ajax/rest?entity=Activity&action=getdayswithactivities&json=%7B%22activity_type_id%22%3A%7B%22!%3D%22%3A%22Bulk+Email%22%7D%2C%22is_deleted%22%3A%220%22%2C%22status_id%22%3A%7B%22IN%22%3A%5B1%2C4%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C2%5D%7D%2C%22activity_date_time%22%3A%7B%22BETWEEN%22%3A%5B%222020-11-01+00%3A00%3A00%22%2C%222020-11-30+23%3A59%3A59%22%5D%7D%2C%22case_id%22%3A%2219%22%2C%22options%22%3A%7B%22group_by_field%22%3A%22status_id%22%7D%7D
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 57ms]

Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 13
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 6
    jQuery 8
    Angular 13
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 32
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 6
    jQuery 8
    Angular 13
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 32
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 6
    jQuery 8
    Angular 13
angular.js:99
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 13
    jQuery 7
    api3 crm.ajax.js:109
    Angular 26
    then jQuery
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 10
    jQuery 3
    onload Common.js:223
    setTimeout handler*CRM.loadScript/script.onload Common.js:219
    loadScript Common.js:217
    Angular 26
    jQuery 3
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 10
    jQuery 3
    onload Common.js:223
    setTimeout handler*CRM.loadScript/script.onload Common.js:219
    loadScript Common.js:217
    Angular 26
    jQuery 3
angular.js:99
GEThttps://crm.thespectrumworks.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.jeditable.min.js?r=hPZWD
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 7ms]

Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 10
    jQuery 3
    onload Common.js:223
    setTimeout handler*CRM.loadScript/script.onload Common.js:219
    loadScript Common.js:217
    Angular 26
    jQuery 3
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 10
    jQuery 3
    onload Common.js:223
    setTimeout handler*CRM.loadScript/script.onload Common.js:219
    loadScript Common.js:217
    Angular 26
    jQuery 3
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 20
    jQuery 3
    onload Common.js:223
    setTimeout handler*CRM.loadScript/script.onload Common.js:219
    loadScript Common.js:217
    Angular 26
    jQuery 3
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 20
    jQuery 3
    onload Common.js:223
    setTimeout handler*CRM.loadScript/script.onload Common.js:219
    loadScript Common.js:217
    Angular 26
    jQuery 3
angular.js:99
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 20
    jQuery 3
    onload Common.js:223
    setTimeout handler*CRM.loadScript/script.onload Common.js:219
    loadScript Common.js:217
    Angular 26
    jQuery 3
angular.js:15635:15
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1…%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D
    Angular 20
    jQuery 3
    onload Common.js:223
    setTimeout handler*CRM.loadScript/script.onload Common.js:219
    loadScript Common.js:217
    Angular 26
    jQuery 3
angular.js:99
```

Comment: Github issue: https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicase/issues/654

Answer (score 1):

It seems ok for me. Did you also update shoreditch? There are a lot of UI changes in core 5.31 that need a recent version of shoreditch.

Angularjs itself was updated in 5.31 - possibly some cached files didn't get cleared. You can also try deleting sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn which is where angular stuff gets cached.

Regarding full_group_by, yeah I have to always turn that off.

Comment: I tried clearing dyn, didn't help. Yes, shoreditch was also updated to the latest. And for full_group_by, that seems kind of dangerous to turn that off. But even when off, the angular errors persist.